# How to return many values in java in this example?

Tags: java

I have a method to find the day after but I don't know how to return all 3 values day,month,year.Please help me. Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
public int dayInMonth(int day,int month,int year){
    //....
    return day;
}

public int theDayAfter(int day, int month, int year) {
    day++;
    int max=dayInMonth(day,month,year);
    if(day>max)
    {
        month++;
        if(month>12)
        {
            year++;
            month=1;
            day=1;
        }
    }
    return ;
}
```

Comment: You could return an `int[]`, a `String` **or** a `Date`. What do you want to do with this? Because it looks like you're trying to re-implement `Calendar`.

Comment: You can't return *three* `int` values from that method, since the return type is just `int`.  Either return *one* `int` or change the return type.  Perhaps to a custom class which itself contains three `int`s?  (Which would also make a good method parameter in this case.)

Comment: return it as a `String`? or an `int[3]` with each index being something

Comment: Ugh, *do not* return a `String` or an `int[]`.  If those three values semantically form a single structure, then *make them a structure*.  (A `class`.)

Comment: Not String, no.  Never encode different values into a single string which then have to be parsed back out.  C.f *Effective Java 2nd ed.*, #10.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch No, I'm just practicing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a valid doubt and a year ago even I was facing such a similar doubt.

I found out that the best way to return such values from a method is to return it in type of an Object. In this example, if I were to return day, month and year then I would create a class as follows:

```
public class DateOfYear{
   public int day;
   public String month;
   public int year;

   public DateOfYear(int day, String month, int year){
       this.day = day;
       this.month = month;
       this.year = year;
   }
}
```

Now I will use this class ***DateofYear*** instantiate it and send values as an object. So, if you would like to get the Day of the month, the function will be as follows:

```
public DateOfYear dayInMonth(int day,int month,int year){
    //....
    return new DateOfYear(day,month,year);
}
```

and the calling function can simply display the current day as follows:

```
System.out.println("Day: "+dayInMonth(day,month,year).day);
```

Similarly for the method ***theDayAfter*** simply change the return type and return the object of type DateOfYear.

```
public DateOfYear theDayAfter(int day, int month, int year) {
    day++;
    int max=dayInMonth(day,month,year);
    if(day>max)
    {
        month++;
        if(month>12)
        {
            year++;
            month=1;
            day=1;
        }
    }
    return new DateOfYear(day, month, year);
}
```

The method calling ***theDayAfter()*** can display the next day as follows:

```
 System.out.println("Next Day: "+theDayAfter(day,month,year).day);
 System.out.println("Month: "+theDayAfter(day,month,year).month);
 System.out.println("Year: "+theDayAfter(day,month,year).year);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .It's look like type struct in C/C++,isn't it?

Comment: Absolutely! Even in those two languages we could send out multiple values by sending out instantiated structs. It's a very useful know-how : to send multiple values from a function. Thanks for marking my response as the answer :)